# How to parse information from a given Wikipedia article

Tags: javascript, html, wikipedia

So, I was making this website that takes date from the user and returns all the historical events that happened on this day.

The natural choice was to use information from the Wikipedia.
Consider for example this article:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/June_23
There is an 'Events' section there, that has it's own id '#Events', so it wouldn't be a problem to find all the necessary information.

So, is it possible to create a new document (using JS), then parse all the information I need and include it on my own page?

If anyone interested that is the website:
http://www.boykodev.com/sites/day-in-history/
I have used an 'iframe' to display the Wikipedia article.

Comment: yes it's possible. can you show what you have so far

Comment: I have an url of Wikipedia page I want to parse. How can I create a document from this url?

Comment: [check this out on how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) it's unlikely that someone is going to do this for you from scratch. have a go then post what you have and where you are stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done with an API.

If you know how to manipulate JSON data you can extract whatever you want from the document.

This is the JSON data from the document you want: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=June_23&rvprop=timestamp|user|comment|content

Check this on how to interpret the data: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=main

Comment: This is a more user friendly version of the second link: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't know JSON yet but I have a good reason to learn it now :)